# libssh: ssh_userauth_none always returning SSH_AUTH_ERROR

Tags: linux, ssh, libssh

In my ssh client I am using `ssh_userauth_none` before calling `ssh_userauth_list()`. But it always returns `SSH_AUTH_ERROR`. When I try to find out the reason for error using `ssh_get_error()` it says `Socket error: disconnected`.

I have used the same code on other linux machine (Ubuntu), it works fine. But when I try it on an embedded machine which is based on CentOS linux, it always fails with the error `-SSH_AUTH_ERROR`.

Am I missing any fields in `ssh_config` file which makes none authentication to work?.

Or is it related to some username/path issue?

Comment: it looks like you got disconneced from server. What are the DEBUG3 level logs on the remote server?

Comment: Why are you calling `ssh_userauth_none`? Just in case it works? Does it fail when you connect from the embedded machine or to the embedded machine?

Comment: I am running both ssh server and client on embedded machine

Comment: one more observation on server side, I see that "ssh_handle_key_exchange" is getting failed